# How to upgrade cassandra dse version 4.8.16 to 6.0.6

Tags: cassandra

I needs to upgrade Cassandra dse version 4.8.16 to 6.0.6 for my Cassandra cluster. Please provide me steps to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I did exactly same thing.

But it is not possible directly:
You must **upgrade DSE from 4.8.16 to 5.0.15** & run sstableupgrade in the end.

1 Problem in doing above: you must move all you client applications to CQL from thrift(if any). However documentation says: it is ok to have Thrift in 5.0.15 but that is not correct(specially for my case).

Once you are on **DSE 5.0.15 you can jump directly to DSE 6.0.6 or DSE 6.7.2** as per [this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE50to67.html). Here also you need to run sstableupgrade.

In whole upgrade process, you need to take care of [Driver's compatibility.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/doc/driver_matrix/javaDrivers.html#java-drivers__java-driver-cstar)